# Produce different serialized JSON for a given class in different scenarios

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

**Update 1:** for reasons I won't go into, I want to avoid having anything other than the properties to be persisted in my entity objects. This means no extra properties or methods...

I have an entity called `Entity1` with (say) 10 public properties.  In
one place in my code I want to output serialized JSON with (say) 3 of
those fields, in a second place I need to output 7 fields and in a
third place I might need to output (say) all 10 fields.  How do I do
this using Newtonsoft's JSON library?

I can't use `[JsonIgnore]` or `[DataMember]` as that will apply to all
cases, so I won't be able to create "custom views" of the data (my own
terminology :-).

I tried to achieve this using an interface:

```
public interface Entity1View1
{
    string Property1;
    string Property2;
    string Property5;
}
```

had `Entity1` implement `Entity1View1` and I passed an
`IList<Entity1View1>` to the JSON serializer (the objects were
actually just `Entity1` objects).  Didn't work: the serializer output
all the 10 public properties of `Entity1`.

The only other way I could think of was to implement
`Entity1Wrapper1`, `Entity1Wrapper2` etc. type of classes where each
object would hold a corresponding instance of `Entity1` and in turn
expose only those public properties that correspond to the properties
I want to show in "View1", "View2" etc.  Then I pass lists of these
wrapper objects to the serializer (should work, haven't tried it yet).

Is there a better way?

If it matters, here's my configuration:

- .Net 4.5
- MVC 5

Comment: clone the Entity before serializing and set the properties which arent needed to null

Comment: How are you using the JSON? Are you preparing an ajax response, or using it some other way?

Comment: @BJSafdie Embedding the generated JSON in a web page for use by jQuery. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @SebastianL will that be cheaper/faster than having a Wrapper object hold a reference to a corresponding `Entity1` object? Will still have to write custom code (for setting specific properties to `null`) for the different "views"/cases.

Comment: Shouldn't your "Custom Views" be objects in their own right? You could have static methods on your Entity that spits out your view objects then serialize those?

Comment: @DavidWatts Yes, that's a definite maybe. Though it doesn't seem very different from using wrappers... maybe more convenient invocation...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update 1:

> [To conditionally serialize a property, add a method that returns boolean with the same name as the property and then prefix the method name with ShouldSerialize.](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm).

This means that the solution suggested by [Raphaël Althaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961526/rapha%c3%abl-althaus) doesn't work as it relies on properties, whereas the serializer's documentation mentions that it has to be a method.  I have verified that only a method returning a `bool` works as expected.

### Original:

I finally went with a mix of Wrapper classes and the methodology suggested by [Raphaël Althaus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961526/rapha%c3%abl-althaus) (with modifications): use Wrappers where some amount of sophistication may be required and use Raphaël's suggestion when simplicity will do.

Here's how I am using wrappers (intentionally left out `null` checks):

```
public class Entity1View1
{
    protected Entity1 wrapped;

    public Entity1View1(Entity1 entity)
    {
        wrapped = entity;
    }

    public String Property1
    {
        get { return wrapped.Property1; }
    }

    public String Property2
    {
        get { return wrapped.Property2; }
    }

    public String Property3
    {
        get { return wrapped.Property3.ToUpper(); }
    }
}
```

This allows me to modify properties as their values are returned (as done with `Property3` above) and lets me leverage inheritance to create new ways of serialization.  For example, I can flatten the structure/hierarchy:

```
public class Entity1View2 : Entity1View1
{
    pulic Entity1View2(Entity1 entity) : base(entity) { }

    public long? SubEntityID
    {
        get { return wrapped.SubEntity.ID; }
    }
}
```

For simpler cases where complexity/transformation of this sort is not required, I can simply use the `ShouldSerialize*` methods.

Same entity classes, different serialization outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know it that's the best way... but that's one.

One good point is that it will work either with json serialization or xml serialization, for example (which you may don't mind at all).

You can use `ShouldSerialize<yourpropertyName>` to manage what is serialized or not. `<yourpropertyName>` must match exactly the name of the property you wanna manage.

For example

```
public class Entity {
   //assuming you want the default behavior to be "serialize all properties"
   public Entity() {
       ShouldSerializeProperty1 = true;
       ShouldSerializeProperty2 = true;
       ShouldSerializeProperty3 = true;
   }
   public string Property1 {get;set;}
   public bool ShouldSerializeProperty1 {get;set;}

   public string Property2 {get;set;}
   public bool ShouldSerializeProperty2 {get;set;}

   public int Property3 {get;set;}
   public bool ShouldSerializeProperty3 {get;set;}
}
```

Then you could do, before all your serialization (of course, this could / should be extension methods).

```
var list = myListOfEntity;

//serialization1
foreach (var element in list) {
   element.ShouldSerializeProperty3 = false;
}

//or serialization2
foreach (var element in list) {
   element.ShouldSerializeProperty2 = false;
   element.ShouldSerializeProperty3 = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to make sure that this was the final step in processing.

You can create anonymous objects to serialize based on circumstance:

```
var json1Source1 = new {
    Property1 = entityView1.Property1,
    Property3 = entityView1.Property3
};

var json1Source2 = new {
    Property2 = entityView1.Property2,
    Property3 = entityView1.Property3
};
```

You can create jsonSource1 (or 2, 3, 4 etc) as anonymous objects that capture just what you need and then serialize them.  The serializer will not care that they are anonymous.